# analytical solutions of partial differential equation

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve this PDE analytically.

$u_t + bu_x = s$ with $b \in \mathbb{R}$ and a function $s = s(x,t) $, and with initial condition $u(x,0) = u_0(x)$ . Now i have to use the method of characteristics to solve it.

I need to show the solution is given by $u(x,t) = u_0(x-bt) + \int_0^t s(x + b(\tau - t),\tau)d\tau$.

I've been told that the solution of a linear first order PDE can be given by $u = u^* + w$ where w is the solution to the homogenous equation $F(w,w_t,w_x) = 0$ and $u^*$ is the solution to $F(u,u_t,u_x) = f$.

So i use characteristics and get that $w=u_0(x-bt)$ and then i try and solve the inhomogeneous version of the equation. This is where i get stuck trying to find $u^*$.

I let $g'(t) = s(\tau(t),t)$ so $g(t) = \int s(\tau(t),t) dt$ but i know this is wrong. I can almost see how to get the solution but cannot justify it.

EDIT: I see that if i make the substitution $t=\tau$ then i get $dt = d\tau$ so $g(t) = \int s(x-b\tau,\tau)d\tau$. I feel closer to the answer but not quite there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The characteristic is $$x=x_0+b\tau,\quad t=\tau.$$ Then $$\frac{dx}{d\tau} = b,\quad \frac{dt}{d\tau} = 1.$$

Therefore

$$\frac{d}{d\tau}u(x(\tau),t(\tau)) = u_t \frac{dt}{d\tau} + u_x \frac{dx}{d\tau} = u_t+bu_x = s(x(\tau),t(\tau)).$$
This is a first order equation. it has a solution

$$u(x(\tau),t(\tau)) = u(x(0),t(0))+ \int_0^\tau s(x(z),t(z)) dz = u(x_0,0)+ \int_0^\tau s(x_0+bz,z) dz.$$
Or

$$u(x_0+b\tau,\tau) = u(x_0,0)+ \int_0^\tau s(x_0+bz,z) dz.$$
Now we express everything in terms of $x$: $x_0 = x-b\tau$, so
$$u(x,\tau) = u( x-b\tau,0)+ \int_0^\tau s(x-b\tau +bz,z) dz.$$

In order to get your result, you need to make a little change $\tau \to t$.

If you still have any questions, feel free to ask in comments.